# Trying to prevent browser trigger of a cronjob

Tags: php, permissions, cron

So i have a cron job that does a lot of stuff(irrelevant for us now).

I've set the file permission to 744 in hope that it will prevent browser execution of the script.

ideally i would like it to be set so only the server user //cronjob can run the script and not people through their browser which could lead to a lot of problems.

here is how I've set the cron job:

/usr/local/bin/php /home/xxxx/public_html/cron/scriptName.php > cronlogs@xxxx.com
`

Could anyone point me to the right direction regarding this issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put it outside of your `public_html` directory. If it's not served, nobody can trigger it with a browser.

Comment: the file has dependencies on other files that are in public_html and those has dependencies as well

Comment: @NetaMeta: Then change the paths of the `require` statement or whatever you're using to pull in those dependencies.

Comment: Additionally, change the owner. 744 allows full access to the script owner, which we can assume is the web server user since you had the script in public_html. Changing the owner will also disallow any other web-based script from executing it.

Comment: Icktoofay yea, that's an idea I'll try it however for now i am trying to see if there's a different solution. George how can i change the owner ?

Comment: To change the owner: `chown <new username> scriptName.php`

Comment: I see. ok Thanks you both very much i will investigate farther